# Rebooting JBoss / Wildfly causes webstart to load all jar files again

Tags: jboss, weblogic, updates, java-web-start

We are developing a software that runs on a client pc and is loaded via webstart (JNLP) from an app server. As app server our customers have the choice between weblogic and jboss ( wildfly). All the jars, the webstart client loads via webstart, are packed within a WAR file deployed in the app server.
The war file does not contain any other things than the jars.
We currently encounter the following issue:
Every time we reboot the jboss, the webstart clients load all the jar files again afterwards although they did not change.
With weblogic we do not have this issue.
Any idea what causes that and how to stop that behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it would be different between Weblogic and JBoss but you should do the following in your JNLP file:

- Specify a version for every jar like:

`<jar href="my.jar" main="true" version="1.0"/>`

- Specify JNLP version enabled

`<property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>`

This should ensure that the versions are checked and only downloaded as needed. You can see more in the [Oracle docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/avoidingUnnecessaryUpdateChecks.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your server returns the correct HTTP code.
Webstart (and browsers) send HTTP request to see if a resource is modified. If it is not modified the server should return code "304 Not Modified".

You can use this chrome plugin to monitor HTTP requests and responses:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-http-headers/iaiioopjkcekapmldfgbebdclcnpgnlo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog